# Gutenberg: useDispatch is not a function - @wordpress/data included

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I have the `@wordpress/data` package installed, but I can't use `useDispatch` in my block edit function:

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { useDispatch, useSelect } = wp.data;
.
.
.
registerBlockType( 'rb-bootstrap/grid', {
    ...
    edit: function( props ) {
         const { replaceInnerBlocks } = useDispatch("core/block-editor");
    }
}
```

> TypeError: useDispatch is not a function

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem with `useSelect`. Are you using `create-guten-block` as well?

Comment: @claudio yes I am. Just in case i did reinstalled the @wordpress/data package, but the problem persisted. I ended up using withDispatch so not to keep wasting time, but it would be nice to have something more declarative like useDispatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have the same problem. After I updated Wordpress, window.wp.data.useDispatch was available.

I'm guessing you also have an out of date Wordpress / Gutenberg

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like `wp.data.useDispatch` and `wp.data.useSelect` were implemented in WP 5.3 (released on November 12, 2019). In older versions those are not available and you are supposed to use `compose`. [This article](https://awhitepixel.com/blog/gutenberg-updating-withselect-and-withdispatch-into-react-hooks-useselect-and-usedispatch/) details how it was on 5.2 and before, and how it is now (much cleaner code).